# Pages has stopped continuing a list on Enter

Tags: pages

Can't figure out how to resolve this issue. The previous behavior is that when creating and editing a list when you press enter you will drop to a new line with a new numbered item.

Somehow, the settings got messed up and now hitting enter on any numbered item will give me a line break but does not continue with the list. I have each one set to "Continue from previous" but it doesn't work for me at all.

How can I set it back to continue all lists when I hit enter?

Edit: Here is an image of the format on a list item:

[image]

Comment: I don't know the answer, sorry - but just to clarify, are you hitting Enter or Return. Some apps treat those as separate commands, though idk how that works for laptops with only one key.

Comment: What do you see under Bullets & Lists in the Text settings in the inspector?

Answer (score 1):

With your cursor at the end of a list item, Go to the Format Inspector (Paint Brush) and toward the bottom you should see a **Bullets & Lists** disclosure arrow.  Check that in the drop down you have selected a bullet style and not **None**.

**CAUTION:** Hitting <kbd>Return</kbd> twice will stop the numbering or bullets.

Example:

[image: Bullets and Lists inspector]

Comment: Added an edit to show what my page's format looks like.